# RestAssured - Returns result as a Map when retrieving a response of a particular path

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

The response from my API is

```
{
"new": {
    "new1": "value1",
    "new2": "value2"
}
}
```

When I try to get what is there in jsonPath of "new" using

```
response.jsonPath().getJsonObject("new").toString()
```

The above query returns something like below, which is kind of a map

```
"new1"="value1","new2"="value2"
```

The response what I look for is,

```
{
    "new1": "value1",
    "new2": "value2"
}
```

Tried many other ways as well , but it returns a map only

Answer (score 0):

`JsonPath` converts input to map and then works with it. You can try extracting required object/map and then convert it back to JSON string using Jackson's [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) (or another JSON parser):

```
Object extracted = response.jsonPath().get("new");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String value = null;
try {
  value = mapper.writeValueAsString(extracted);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is there a method in RestAssured itself where it takes the result as a String not as a Map